# Java exception in openConnection method (fetching data from html)

Tags: java, urlconnection, oai

I have a problem getting the input stream using 'getInputStream' method for few URLs (most of the URLs works fine) although the URL seems to work via web browser.

I am using the following code:

```
public static String getContents(String uri, String encoding) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    URL url;

    try {
        url = new URL(uri);

        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        con.setReadTimeout(90000);

        System.out.println("--------2.1:");//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream(); 
        System.out.println("--------2.2:"+is);/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        // read lines from HTML
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("--------2.6:");//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        return null;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

output:

```
--------2.1:http://infoscience.epfl.ch/oai2d?verb=ListIdentifiers&metadataPrefix=oai_dc
--------2.6:
```

Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://infoscience.epfl.ch/oai2d?verb=ListIdentifiers&metadataPrefix=oai_dc
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.irWizard.common.util.FileUtils.getContents(FileUtils.java:29)
at com.irWizard.web.controller.WizardController.getActualTotalOfRecords(WizardController.java:500)
at com.irWizard.web.controller.WizardController.validateSets(WizardController.java:419)
at com.irWizard.web.controller.WizardController.onSubmit(WizardController.java:242)
at com.irWizard.web.controller.BaseController.onSubmit(BaseController.java:127)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController.processFormSubmission(SimpleFormController.java:258)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleInvalidSubmit(AbstractFormController.java:652)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:257)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:45)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:728)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:396)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:350)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It seems that it's code 503.
Does anyone know how it can be solved? (it works fine via browser).

Mike

Comment: Mike can you print the exception and provide the logs?

Comment: Added, it seems like code 503 issue but how can I solve it (works via browser).

Comment: I've tested you code several times and does not throws exception. It is server issue..  503 Service Unavailable

`The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server.`

Comment: from browser I'm receiving `Retry after 10 seconds` After I refresh the page few times

Comment: Is there something I can do? why it works fine via web browser (firefox)? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to order the connection via URLConnection class to wait these 10 seconds? or there is nothing I can do from my side because the problem is with the remote server? Thanks!

Comment: There is properties `connectionTimeout` and `readTimeout` but you cannot do nothing from your side...